# Prevent String.Contains from matching empty

Tags: kotlin

I'm running a `filter` command on an object in kotlin and trying to match results. I didn't realize until today that an empty string will match any string in a contains query as follows:

```
var brandname = ""
var brandtofind = "tide"
var result = brandtofind.contains(brandname) //results in true
```

This is problematic when you are trying to match entries where a string can be empty as follows:

```
var candidates = this.filter{ product -> 
                  text.contains(product.name) ||
                  text.contains(product.brandname) //brandname often empty
```

I get massive numbers of false positives on products without a brand name. How do I alter the query to only match when there is a true match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a check for [`product.brandname.isNotBlank()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-not-blank.html), which is an enhanced verions of [`isNotEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-not-empty.html)

```
var candidates = this.filter{ product -> 
                  text.contains(product.name) ||
                  (product.brandname.isNotBlank() && text.contains(product.brandname))}
```